# Java encryption files using AES - Best Methods

Tags: java, image, encryption, cryptography

I have searched around for the best methods for encryption in terms of what ciphers to use, methods/etc. I'v decided on using 128Bit AES for the time being. My question lies more in what method is best for encrypting various types of data. In my example, this is for a small game I am making that has map data and associated image data.

I can save the data in any format, but would prefer something simple to read (when un-encrypted). Should I actually save this to the file itself, or should I change the file itself in some way?

Likewise in terms of the image files associated to the game that are saved as PNG or BMP files, any recommendations on how to encrypt those on top of the rest of the files?

My current method for the game data is to just encrypt it in singular lines - and have it load from a file line-by-line. Each line formatting to a different data value to be put into the system (e.g. load part of a map, maybe some item data, etc). Is there a better/faster method of accomplishing this that I may not have found yet?

I was also wondering about actually taking the entire class with the data saved and serializing it - then encrypting it. That way I could load the entire thing in one go straight into a class. Would this be a reasonable idea?

Comment: *"I've decided on using 128Bit AES for the time being.."* - and what mode have you decided on? *"My current method for the game data..."* - Oh, this complicates things. Where is the key stored?

Comment: I'v currently got a fixed key on the game itself. I understand this is measurably weak considering it would not be hard to decompile the program and find it. Its another follow up question I may have in terms of what method might be used to decrypt it. I am assuming its probably going to be a matter of authenticating it at run time against the server, or the server sending a key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the images: you can read them using a `CipherInputStream` / `CipherOuputStream`. Note that *at least* older Java versions ignored padding errors for `CipherInputStream`.

You cannot directly encrypt to lines as the output of a cipher is binary. So you need to encode (using e.g. Base64) if you want to store the result as lines. You may ask yourself if you want things like game data to be in text. I would recommend CBC mode with random IV prefixed to the ciphertext.

If the data is serializable then serializing data could be an option. Personally I'm not a huge fan of serialization in Java due to the many pitfalls. But yes, you can certainly encrypt serialized data easily, it's binary after all.

Comment: Yes, I found that out while making the encryption the first time. I am currently saving them in base64 character encoding. Thank you for the advise on the CipherInputStream - I'll look into that.

I'll also take a look into the CBC mode you mentioned. Have not heard of it before, so I will have to do some digging. Lastly have not heard about serialization previously - but will look into it. Im most tempted to look into that since it is something I know about already. Thank for the advise.

Comment: After taking only a few minutes to read into some of the pitfalls of Serialization - I am probably not going to go with it as an option. The classes I want to serialize, while small individually make up a lot of data over all. Plus most of my classes will probably change around in both function and setup - so having just data encrypted would be preferable. I think for a simple solution for the time being I'll just encrypt the data as planned and work out the issue with the key later.